# Can get User Department via JSOM or REST (no UPA)?

Tags: 2013, javascript, client-object-model, rest

The farm has not UPA service deployed and I wouldn't do it.

Is it possible to retrieve using JSOM or REST one of the properties that we see in the `_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx?` page for a specific user?

1. I don't find any documentation about getting the user information (no user profile) using JSOM.
2. I thought I could be able to access these properties using REST (http://sympmarc.com/2014/01/21/getting-user-information-with-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api/) but I get null for the Department property even if the property is set for the specified user.
3. As suggested by the @harryB's answer, there is endpoint `siteuserinfolist`, however with this REST call I still get a null value for department:

   ```
                          `<d:Department m:null="true" />`
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`REST` end point for getting details for a particular user from the User Information List as below: 
For example below request would get the details of a user with userid (item id in the User Info List) = 16

```
http://site/_api/web/siteUserInfoList/items(16)
```

Comment: I tried this endpoint and it works fine. However I still see the property null. Please check my question update.

Comment: This information might be helpful for you. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2a50a44b-4e32-4132-bac2-40a2b9249eb1/reset-user-information-list-without-user-profile-service

Comment: Thanks really helpful. I've just found an issue on my tests, and I can see now data returned in the correct way. So your suggestion works, and the method .2 in my question too works.